# al iterar un array siempre me muestra el ultimo elemento de la lista pero no los demas

Tags: javascript, array, arraylist, javascript-objeto

tengo una consulta , estoy iterando un array con `map` , estoy guardando el resultado en una variable global que es `guideNumber` , pero solo me imprime el ultimo valor cuando hago el `console.log()` fuera de la función y no me muestra los demás valores. Dejo el código

```js
services: "[{"serviceId": 117, "workOrder": "2356", "guideNumber": 8900}, {"serviceId": 122, "workOrder": "86", "guideNumber": 4554}, {"serviceId": 123, "workOrder": "1001", "guideNumber": 6665}]"
status: "Ingresado"
statusId: 1
travelDate: 1624579200
travelId: 98
travelWorkOrder: 4554
user: "Soporte MT"
statusCode: 200

let guideNumber:any;

let arraysOt:OT[] = JSON.parse(programming.services);
  function getGuideNumber(){
    arraysOt.map(item => {
      guideNumber = item.guideNumber
      console.log('items ',guideNumber)
      return
    })
  }
  
  console.log('=====> ed',guideNumber)
```

El log me muestra ===> `"items" 6665` y nos los otros (los valores de `guideNumber`, los necesito para pintarlos en una tabla)

Comment: guideNumber = item.guideNumber aqui estas reemplazando el valor de guideNumber cada loop cierto? Y eso es lo que muestras en console.log('=====> ed',guideNumber)

Comment: @angeReyna si en guideNumber guardo al valor de cada item y es lo que imprimo en el log , pero me entrega el valor del ultimo guideNumber del array de services y necesito los otros para poder pintarlos tambien , esa es la duda , no se como obtener los otros dos :(

Comment: `let guideNumber = arraysOt.map(item => item.guideNumber)` quizá

Comment: emeeus , si pero como guardo los resultados de item.guideNumber ? para poder pintar cada valor en template, por eso tenia la duda si es correcto guardarla en una variable global para retornarla y mostrar el resultado

Comment: asi queda guardado en `guideNumber`

Comment: de hecho no es necesaria la funcion `get`

Answer (score 3):

Debes entender mejor la documentacion de [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
services: "[{"serviceId": 117, "workOrder": "2356", "guideNumber": 8900}, {"serviceId": 122, "workOrder": "86", "guideNumber": 4554}, {"serviceId": 123, "workOrder": "1001", "guideNumber": 6665}]"
status: "Ingresado"
statusId: 1
travelDate: 1624579200
travelId: 98
travelWorkOrder: 4554
user: "Soporte MT"
statusCode: 200

let arraysOt: OT[] = JSON.parse(programming.services);

let guideNumber: any = arraysOt.map(item => item.guideNumber);

console.log('=====> ed', guideNumber)
```